# Verilog: error: unmatched character (hex)

Tags: unicode, verilog

I have written a shift/add multiplier in Verilog that compiles without error through online compilers, but when i try to compile it with iverilog through the CMD window i receive the following error:

> shiftadd.v:1:error: unmatched character (hex U+019E)

(U+019E is the closest unicode character I could find to what it is). What in my code is causing this error? I am not trying to pass any hexadecimal values.

```
module shiftaddmult(product, multiplicand, multiplier, clk);
    input clk;

    output reg [63:0] product;
    input [63:0] multiplicand;
    input [31:0] multiplier;
    integer i;

    always @(posedge clk)        //m or m
    begin

        if(i< 32)
        begin


            product[63:32] = 16'b0000_0000_0000_0000;    
            product[32:16] = multiplier;


            if(product[0] == 1)
                begin
                    product[63:32] = product[63:32] + multiplicand;
                    product [63:0] = product[63:1];
                end

            else
                begin
                 product [63:0] = product[63:1];
                end
        i = i + 1;

        end
    end                        //end always
endmodule        //shift add



module tester(output reg [63:0] product,
              output reg [63:0] multiplicand,
              output reg [31:0] multiplier,
              output reg clk,
              output reg i);
initial
        begin

        i = 0;
        clk = 0;

        $dumpfile("multdump.dat");
        $dumpvars;


        #10 multiplier   = 16'b0000_0000_0000_0001;
                multiplicand = 16'b0000_0000_0000_0010;

                //result should = 2


        #20 multiplier   = 16'b0000_0000_0000_0010;
                multiplicand = 16'b0000_0000_0000_0100;


                //result should = 'd8

        #30 multiplier   = 16'b0000_0000_0000_1000;
            multiplicand = 16'b0000_0000_0000_1000;

                //result should = 'd16    
        #40 $finish;
        end

        always begin
                #5 clk = ~clk;    //clock generator
        end
endmodule

module testbench;

wire [63:0] product;
wire [63:0] multiplicand;
wire [31:0] multiplier;

wire i;
wire clk;

tester test(product, multiplicand, multiplier, clk, i);
shiftaddmult mult(product, multiplicand, multiplier, clk);

endmodule
```

Comment: What is the character?

Comment: Show the command line as well. This code compiles perfectly for me.

Comment: @EugeneSh. i edited the post to include the unicode number of the character it most closes resembles

Comment: @enkayh Try to copy/paste the code from this page to a new file and compile it. If there are some invalid characters, it will get rid of them.

Comment: @EugeneSh.I tried this multiple times with no luck. same error gets printed out

Comment: @enkayh So what is the command you are using to compile?

Comment: @EugeneSh. iverilog -o samultiply samultiply.v   i just switched computers and was able to compile it. If it happens again i'll post back. If not, thank you for the help!

Comment: Well, it works perfectly for me with the latest iverilog (0.9.7) for windows

Comment: @EugeneSh.I got it working, seemed to be the computer, not the code. Looking at the output I see that the product register is not outputting anything. Do you see where the error is? I thought it was coded correctly

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are copying code from browser and pasting it in your source code. Copying the code from browser also copies some special characters which cannot be detected by the compiler.
I suggest you write code again do not copy and paste. Just write those lines again using keyboard.
This should work and eliminate unwanted characters.